# Angularjs $http get json data, but won't display

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, api

I am new to angularjs, and I try to async load data by using angularjs.

## Json Sample

```
[{"id":153,"name":"Computer Parts->Cooling Device->CPU Fan"},{"id":30,"name":"Computer Parts->CPU"}]
```

## HTML Code

```js
 var homeApp = angular.module('managementApp',[]);
        homeApp.controller('categoryMgmt',function($scope,$http){
            $scope.categoryFilter = '';
            $scope.categorys = '';
            $scope.categoryLoad = function(){
                var key = $scope.categoryFilter;

                $http({
                    method : 'get',
                    url : 'hugo.dev/api/categorys/'+key,
                    
                }).then(function mySuccess(response){
                    $scope.categorys = angular.fromJson(response.data);
                    console.log($scope.categorys[0].name);

                });
            };
        });
```

```html
    <script src="http://cdn.static.runoob.com/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" ng-app="managementApp" ng-controller="categoryMgmt">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <input name="categoryName" class="form-control" ng-model="categoryFilter">
    <div class="list-group" ng-show="categoryFilter" >
      <a ng-repeat="item in categorys" href="#" class="list-group-item">{{ item.name }}</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  <button type="button" ng-click="categoryLoad()">asd</button>

</div>
```

## Console Output

```
Computer Parts->Cooling Device->CPU Fan
```

The question is, ng-repeat work fine, there are two  tags appead in the list,but ***{{ item.name }}*** can not read any data. I don't know why.The result [#SnapShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzMNu.png), Please Help!

Comment: I don't think you'd need `fromJson()`, just set `$scope.categorys = response.data;`

Comment: Hi, I removed the fromjson() before, same issue. Cheers

Comment: Instead of the `<a>` inside the the `list-group` just print out `{{ item }}` and see what the output is to ensure all properties are coming through. `<div ng-repeat="item in categorys">{{ item }}</div>`.

Comment: Try $scope.categorys = response.data directly. If that does not work check  this code $scope.categorys = JSON.parse(response.data ); or JSON.parse(response).data The second and third are not needed generally.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything wrong with the code you posted. As Alexander pointed out, you probably don't need `fromJson()`, but that shouldn't be a problem either.

Here is a working plunker using your same code: https://plnkr.co/edit/GrYZZLjYc9mwCj7dAs5Z?p=preview

The only thing I changed was to pull the data from file since I don't have your service:

```
// url : 'hugo.dev/api/categorys/'+key,
url: 'data.json'
```

I guess this isn't necessarily an answer to your problem, but it proves that the code you posted works... your issue must be elsewhere.

Comment: Hi Picazo, thanks very for the test code, It seems work well, it's really weird in my computer...

Answer (score 0):

scope.categorys must be initialize to array and remove fromJson

```
homeApp.controller('categoryMgmt',function($scope,$http){
      $scope.categoryFilter = '';
     // Default to array
     $scope.categorys = [];
     $scope.categoryLoad = function(){
          var key = $scope.categoryFilter;

         $http({
                    method : 'get',
                    url : 'hugo.dev/api/categorys/'+key,

                }).then(function mySuccess(response){
                    // remove fromJson
                    $scope.categorys = response.data;
                    console.log($scope.categorys[0].name);

           });
      };
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you should use `$scope.category` in the html code instead of `{{item.category}}`.